# How to read telnet response in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, telnet

Need to implement communication with server via telnet on Groovy. The problem is that execution is stuck on the `def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))` row because I see both both commands in logs on the server side. Seems like something is wrong with response reading - just nothing happened till I stop the execution.

```
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient

static void main(String[] args) {
  def client = new TelnetClient()
  client.connect('servername.dev.net', 9999)

  def inputStream = client.inputStream
  def outputStream = client.outputStream

// send commands to the server
  outputStream.write("{\"method\":\"authentication\",\"data\":{\"app_key\":\"asdsdfsdfsd\",\"service_id\":1,\"version\":\"4.0.0\"}}\r\n".getBytes())

  Thread.sleep(2000)

  outputStream.write("{\"method\":\"get.news\"}\r\n".getBytes())

// read responses from the server
  def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
  def response = reader.readLine()

  while (response != null) {
    println(response)
    response = reader.readLine()
  }

  Thread.sleep(15000)

// close the connection
  client.disconnect()
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what if you use `client.outputStream.withReader{}` instead of piling up the readers yourself?

Comment: Quite sure you should use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available-- to read response.